# Using pray instead of please in a sentence - Why? When?

Tags: british-english, archaicisms

I hear (mostly from people in the Humanities department) sentences that use pray instead of the word please:

*"Pray tell me, when will you be back?"*

Assuming that I haven't made any mistakes in the above, I find this formulation very beautiful, also respectful.

However, I am unaware of when to use such a formulation.

Am I correct to understand that pray can generally replace the word please in sentences similar to the one above?

Why, or in which situations is such a formulation favoured, or  disfavoured?

Has such a formulation become archaic now?

Many thanks.

Comment: *[pray](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pray), adv.* ***formal or archaic.*** *1. Used as a preface to polite requests or instructions 1.1 Used as a way of adding ironic or sarcastic emphasis to a question.* (ODO)

Comment: @choster, thanks a lot for bringing me back to ODO. Had completely forgotten to check there; perhaps because I work in the Computer Science industry - an industry where a search on Google or forums as StackExchange is the first thing that comes to mind when searching for word meanings. Obviously not a good practice...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is somewhat archaic. Today, certain archaic words are often used satirically, when someone is deliberately being too formal or polite (e.g., "Pray tell me, what can I do for you?" when someone is being a nuisance). Words like *alas* and *daresay* are examples of the same thing--they're usually used when the speaker wants to be satirical or overly dramatic.

Of course, they are sometimes used genuinely, especially in fiction when a writer wants to give the characters an old-fashioned or classical manner of speaking. If you hear this in the Humanities department from, say, English professors, it's quite possible that they're simply imitating the type of speech they appreciate in older works.

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer. Unfortunately, I am unable to upvote the answer, being a new user with less reputation points.